# Is it correct to use future and present tenses with one subject?

Tags: verbs, present-simple, subjects

For example: I agree with the author's opinion and will give some arguments to support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

I agree - present

I will give - future

Comment: Can you expand this with more detail about why to help the OP with their doubts?